# Не работает отправка формы на сервер через ajax-запрос

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Есть код разметки с js скриптами для отправки имени и номера телефона на сервер и нужно дать обратный ответ, если данные отправились, но ничего не работает, код ниже:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .formContactSend {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .formContactSend. sended {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .error {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>

  <form id="myform" class="form-ajax" action="/smec1.php" method="post">
    <div>Name</div>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form__name" required placeholder="Введите имя">
    <br>
    <div>Tel</div>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" required class="form__phone">
    <button type="button">Сделать заказ</button>
    <!--<input class="inp" type="hidden" name="topicForm" value="Верхняя форма">-->
    <div class="inpobrddiv">
      <input type="checkbox" class="inpobrd" name="inpobrd" id="inpobrd1"> <label for="inpobrd">Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на обработку своих персональных данных</label>
    </div>
    <div class="formContactSend">
      <div class="h2q">Спасибо за Ваше обращение!</div>
      <p class="form1error">В течение 5 секунд к Вам поступит СМС-уведомление о принятии заявки!<br> Если СМС-уведомление не поступило, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА повторите заказ!<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="result_form"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      //2. Получить элемент, к которому необходимо добавить маску
      $("#phone").mask("+7(999) 999-9999");

      //получить форму и отправить данные
      $('.form-ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $self = $(this);

        $self.validate({
          rules: {
            name: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 4
            },
            phone: {
              required: true
            },
            inpobrd: {
              required: true
            }
          }
        });

        var name = $('.form__name').val();

        var tel = $('.form__phone').val();

        var url = $self.attr('action'),

          data = $self.serialize();

        var thisLink = document.location.href;


        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: data,
          sucess: function(data) {
            data = "name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) + "&phone=" + tel + "&email=" + thisLink;

            bhag_leadga(data);
            $("#yacnew").click();

            Comagic.push(['addOfflineRequest', {
              name: name,
              phone: tel
            }]);

            Comagic.sitePhoneCall({
              phone: tel
            });

            $('.formContactSend').addClass('sended');

          },
          error: function(data) { // Данные не отправлены
            document.getElementById(result_form).innerHTML = "Ошибка. Данные не отправленны.";
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: насколько мне известно, `.on('submit'` подразумевает отправку формы, т.е. должна быть кнопка отправки `<button type="submit">отправить</button>`

Comment: спасибо, добавила, но при клике на кнопку отправки к тегу формы отрисовывается novalidate="novalidate"

Comment: а как можно проверить, что моя форма правильно работает? При добавлении <div id="result_form"></div> и  document.getElementById(result_form).innerHTML = "Данные отправленны."; сообщение не выводится

Comment: `document.getElementById("result_form").innerHTML = "Данные отправленны.";`